# Reduce method returns

Tags: javascript

Why does the second assignment need return and the first returns variable total automatically?

```
const total = inventors.reduce(((total, inventor) => total += inventor.passed - inventor.born), 0);
```

```
const transportation = data.reduce(((prevVal, currentVal) => {
      if (!prevVal[currentVal]) {
        prevVal[currentVal] = 0;
      }
      prevVal[currentVal]++;
      return prevVal;
    }), {})
```

If return prevVal is omitted I get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined**

What is the difference in how reduce() acts with values. Is it effected by ternary operation? If so then why this returns 0?

```
const transportation = data.reduce(((prevVal, currentVal) => 
(!prevVal[currentVal]) ? prevVal[currentVal] = 0 : prevVal[currentVal]++), {})
```

Comment: This is how [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#basic_syntax) work.

Comment: That is just how the syntax works. If you leave out the `{}` in an arrow function's right side, the right side is expected to be an expression and automatically returned.

Answer (score 0):

When using curly braces with an arrow function, the return is not implicit, so you have to use `return`